# Unable to download file from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using following code to download an image from Amazon S3:

```
 router.post('/image-upload', function (req, res, next) {

    if (!req.files)
        return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');

    var file = req.files['image_' + req.session.sessID];

    AWS.config.loadFromPath(<credentials_path>);

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    var params = {Bucket: credentials.aws_s3.bucket_name, Key: req.session.email, Body: file.data};

    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err)

        } else {

            var options = {
                Bucket: credentials.aws_s3.bucket_name,
                Key: req.session.email
            };

            var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', options);
            console.log(url);

        }
    });
});
```

I am getting url in following form:

```
https://[S3 BUCKET].s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/[KEY]?X-Amz-Algorithm=[VALUE]&amp;X-Amz-Credential=[VALUE]&amp;X-Amz-Date=20170427T111724Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=60&amp;X-Amz-Signature=[VALUE]&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=[VALUE]
```

However, when I try to open this link in browser, I am getting following error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
<Message>
Query-string authentication version 4 requires the X-Amz-Algorithm, X-Amz-Credential, X-Amz-Signature, X-Amz-Date, X-Amz-SignedHeaders, and X-Amz-Expires parameters.
</Message>
<RequestId>29819210D89C8877</RequestId>
<HostId>
aPpmRMYB7QCog4UDqs1j2rCdY3cy5H8u3kGE8nv2qXF6Y2iATPNquz+MQNdvr3zZ1ceRydRplq0=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I am unable to understand why this error, as the returned url has all the requisite query parameters. Can anyone please help??

Comment: Can you provide more of your code so we can see how you created the `s3` object? Which language are you using?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i have added the complete code. I am using Node Express. What I want to do is send the url of image stored in S3 to the javascript and display image on webpage.

Comment: The URL *appears* to have the required parameters but the `&amp;`s should not be there.  Query string parameters are separated with `&` and this xml-escaped form is not valid.  It's not clear where that is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: You must ensure that you have static or previously resolved credentials if you call this method synchronously (with no callback), otherwise it may not properly sign the request. If you cannot guarantee this (you are using an asynchronous credential provider, i.e., EC2 IAM roles), you should always call this method with an asynchronous callback.

Try instead to retrieve the signed url inside the methods callback function.

```
s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', options, function(err, url) {
  console.log(url);
});
```